# sudo easy_install wstool rospkg rosdep

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello friends,
When i run this command on Raspberry pi,i'm getting this messages on terminal

[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source)

### Message:

### Searching for wstool
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/wstool/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/wstool/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/wstool/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/wstool/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'wstool' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for wstool
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('wstool')

Can you please suggest best way to comeback.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59320/sudo-easy_install-wstool-rospkg-rosdep/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

**Just run same command with ABC changes**

sudo -E easy_install wstool rospkg rosdep

**This will may work fine.**

---

Originally posted by [learner](https://answers.ros.org/users/4414/learner/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on 2013-03-26**:
Thanks that looks like it works fine
sudo -E easy_install virtualenv
The -E switch preserves your current environment.
Info

http://superuser.com/questions/258819/easy-install-will-not-connect-through-proxy